# Need to make Stack cards on nav click as well ass page scroll with help of jquery

Tags: stack

[I want to make it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYEDV.png)
which will work on page scroll as well as nav click.

$('nav a').on('click', function() {
var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 0;

```
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
        
    }, 500);
    return false;

    })


    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (windscroll >= 100) {
          $('nav').addClass('fixed');
          $('.wrapper section').each(function(i) {
              if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20) {
                  $(this).addClass('active');
                  $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                  $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
              }
          });

      } else {
          $('section').removeClass('active');
          $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
          $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
          $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
      }
    }).scroll();
```